# Search Mapbox dataset

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I use a Mapbox dataset converted to a tileset to show features on a map. I would like to add a search facility which goes through all the features in the dataset (not only the one shown on the screen which I could search locally thanks to [queryRenderedFeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api#map#queryrenderedfeatures)).

I do not see how to do this without implementing my own search facility server side. I would like to avoid that because it would mean my dataset needs to be stored at two different places (on Mapbox and on my server).

In this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42429196/2924547), someone suggested to use [querySourceFeatures](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#querysourcefeatures) but it only checks features in the currently visible viewport.

Did I miss any search through dataset facility offered by Mapbox ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Datasets API to download you whole GeoJSON dataset to the client, then using the mapbox-gl-geocoder's localGeocoder option implement you own custom search.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewHarvey, I could do that, but I wanted to avoid downloading the whole dataset locally. That's why I used the tilesets in the first place and I was thinking of implementing my own search facility server side.